# Specialize function template by static value in class of template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have function `op` and I would like to specialize it for all cases where template parameter `PROCESSOR::DIMENSION = 2`. Is that possible at all or how could I achieve something similiar?

```
// How to specialize this for all PROCESSOR with DIMENSION = 2?
template <class PROCESSOR>
void op(Node<PROCESSOR>& node){

}


// this is an example for template parameter PROCESSOR
template <int DIM>
class CPU
{
    public:
        static int DIMENSION = DIM;

};
```

(If you suspect a XY question, you might be right. I have a relatively complicated design task here, and I'm evaluating different ideas how to do it. One of them leads to the above X. Particularly, I try to avoid polymorphic pointers since they would prevent the compiler from inlining and we are talking about very small code snippets for a high performance application.)

Comment: Is PROCESSOR and CPU the same? if so, please correct your question!

Comment: CPU can be used as template parameter PROCESSOR, like: `op<CPU<2>>(n)`.

Comment: Don't worry, seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like  this. Please note, you cannot partially specialize functions:

```
template <class PROCESSOR, int D = PROCESSOR::DIM>
struct op
{
  void operator()(...);
};

template <class PROCESSOR>
struct op<PROCESSOR, 2>
{
  void operator()(...);
};
```